# How to convert Arrow function to regular function

Tags: javascript

I have this sample here and I would like to convert the Arrow function to a normal function but didn't know how to do so. Thanks

```
const intialValue = 0
const lineItems = [
  { description: 'Eggs (Dozen)', quantity: 1, price: 3, total: 3 },
  { description: 'Cheese', quantity: 0.5, price: 5, total: 2.5 },
  { description: 'Butter', quantity: 2, price: 6, total: 12 }
];
const tt = lineItems.reduce((sum, li) => sum + li.total, intialValue)
console.log(tt)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You are question blocked on [so]. That doesn't mean you can ask your off-topic programming questions on [su]. See [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please also read [ask] and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert an arrow function to non-arrow, you need to give it a name:

```
function mysumfunc (sum, li) {
    return sum + li.total;
};
```

To understand better the JavaScript
[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce),
see this more explicit example:

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
const initialValue = 0;
const sumWithInitial = array1.reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
  initialValue
);
```

Comment: Please can you stop answering off topic questions?. You have been asked to do this multiple times.

Comment: @DavidPostill: JavaScript is now off-topic? So where is it on-topic?

Comment: Read the tag...

Comment: @DavidPostill: There are 846 questions with this tag. I've often included JavaScript in my Greasemonkey answers. So what can I say...